# What is elastic and its related products?

Tags: elasticsearch

Just going to implement elastic search log related task.

Have some questions about elastic:

What is elastic? does it mean flexible stuff?
What is elastic search? (https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch)
what is elastic cache?
what is the relationship between elastic search and elastic cache?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what relates ES with EC, but simply `Elastic Search` is where you index all the data you need, let it be log files or the data from a database. You could store them as docs within an index and then query in order retrieve data from the index.

This is what I got from my neighborhood friend `Google`:

> Elasticsearch is a search engine based on Lucene. It provides a
>   distributed, multitenant-capable full-text search engine with an HTTP
>   web interface and schema-free JSON documents.

Comment: Could i know the reason for the downvote please? So that I could correct my answer.